# Chosen.js referencing an option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

has anyone any experience with chosen.js? : http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

An issue hopefully someone can point me in the right direction..

`<select title="Choose a Body Part" id="body-chart-dd"  style="width:295px;" tabindex="2">`
`<option value="a1">Face</option>`
`<option value="a2">Legs</option>`
`</select>`

It just generates `<li id="body-chart-ddchzn_o_1">Face</li>` etc .. How can I grab the a1 ... a2 values? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#body-chart-dd option").each(function(){

alert($(this).text());
});
```

hereis the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UNXtz/